# Where is stored a variable declared in an IIFE?

Tags: javascript

In the following example

```
var foo = "bar;

(function () {    
    var hello = "world";
    debugger;
}());
```

the variable foo is declared in the global scope, thus it becomes a property of `window` and the expression `window.foo` returns "bar".

If I stop at the breakpoint in the *iife* and type `hello` in the terminal, it returns world.

But on which object is the variable `hello` stored in?

Comment: it will have local scope limited to that Anonymous function

Comment: Sure but is it referenced by a variable ?

Comment: It will be referenced as "hello" locally within the function, but it will not be visible from outside of the anonymous function.

Comment: Make them both have same variable name...that might make it clearer for you

Comment: it won't be set as property of some object like declaring in global scope sets the declared variable as a property of window ?

Comment: @Lev no it will not, `window.hello` is undefined

Comment: @Lev local scopes are *like* objects, but they're not directly accessible as such.

Answer (score 2):

It will have local scope limited to that anonymous function

unless specified it will not associated with any object.In your code it exists independently as hello itself and will not be accessible out side that function

```
var foo = "bar;

(function () {

    var hello = "world";
    debugger;

}());
```

If you want it to be associated with any object you could do it as

```js
var foo = "bar";
var obj={};

(function () {
  obj.hello="world";
console.log(obj.hello);
})()
console.log(obj.hello);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Actually you don't need to pass obj as an argument to the IIFE as the global scope is accessible from inside the function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Global scope variables are a syntactic sugar of adding a property to the global object `window` or  `global` in NodeJS: `var a = 11;` is the same as `window.a = 11;`.

How local variables are stored in memory is a concrete JavaScript runtime implementation detail. I wouldn't mind about how's stored since it has no interest in a high level language like JavaScript. They're just *variables* like in any other old or modern programming language.

Maybe you'll find this other Q&A a good resource to learn more about JavaScript scoping: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)